# Order in rails form dropdown including priority

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown on a rails form and I would like to order all the names in it by alphabetical order. However I would also like the first 3 names in the drop down to always be the same regardless of the aphabetic ordering. How do I go about doing this?

For Example (Drop Down Content, where John, Jane and Peter always have priority):
John 
Jane 
Peter 
Alison 
Betty 
Cathy 
David

My dropdown is currently defined as follows:

```
<%= f.select :name_id, Name.all.map { |x| [x.name, x.id]}, :include_blank => 'Select a name' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your model `Name` has a field `at_top`, which is set to true for John, Jane and Peter. Then you can:

```
Name.order('at_top DESC, name ASC')
```

Comment: Is it possible to this without the field at_top on the model.

Comment: Yes, you can - but you must figure out how to specify the *priority*. For example, you can pull out the three names manually (in an array), place them at top, and then fetch others in alphabetical order.